# How to compare numeric and string values same times in Entity framework in C# with Lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

[image: I want to compare a search value the table columns fields, if I compare only string values with contains property, no error but in case of adding numeric value, showing "does not take 1 argument"]

I want to compare a search value the table columns fields, if I compare only string values with contains property, no error but in case comparing both numeric and String values, showing

> does not take 1 argument

as displayed in attached picture

Comment: BTW you don't need to provide some default value for variable before assignment. You can use simply `int id = int.Parse(searchText)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using single `=` which is assignment operator. For comparison use `==` operator:

```
Where(p => p.VenerName.Contains(searchText) || p.PrimaryContact == id)
```

Comment: One more thing sir, in the above if i filter in function Int value its ok but if i filter string value it shows that "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: @Hamid that means your searchText cannot be parsed into integer value. To avoid this exception you can use `Int32.TryParse` method, which returns true if value parsed successfully (and you can execute query) or it returns false (and you should show error message to user)

Comment: @Hamid you should specify `out` parameter. [Take a look on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)

Comment: i did this one, int id = Int32.TryParse(searchText); but showing "No overload method for doesn't take one argument"

Comment: @Hamid take a look on link provided, and carefully watch on method signature which you are using